# How can I force SSIS to re-validate?

Tags: ssis

So I'm working with SSIS and I need to do have a T-SQL task that alters some columns. During testing I obviously need to change them back, re-run the task, again and again. But after each run, I get a `VS_ISBROKEN` error... which is perfectly reasonable, since I *have* changed stuff. However, if I go into SSMS and change everything back to what it was at first, I can't find a way to get SSIS to re-validate without closing and reopening it.

I've tried resetting the destination connection string and creating a new destination object, but the error persists until I restart SSIS. What am I missing?

Comment: I really question whether this is a good idea. Maybe create one package that modifies the columns, and create a second package that uses the modified columns. When you need to start over, execute a script that puts things back the way they were.

Comment: Usually when you double click on the task with an exclamation mark it recognises it and prompts you to refresh metadata and hopefull can automatically match it all up again. Why are you altering column like this? sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @JohnSaunders are you saying that it's a bad idea to modify and then use them in the same package? Why? That part is working... Anyhow, that's what I'm doing (running a script that resets things), only doing it in SSMS instead of a separate SSIS task/package

Comment: Yes, use separate packages. That way, the one that's currently giving you an error will always deal with the new set of columns.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm encrypting existing data back into the same field, so I create a new varbinary column, encrypt data into it, delete the old column, and then rename the new encrypted one to the old column's name.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that makes sense, I'll try doing that

Comment: I'm not too familiar with encryption, Can't you just update the existing field?